# Combining two dataframes based on two columns values in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a dafarame like this:

df1:

```
     col1  col2        data1       data2    data3
0     A     A_1         2            4        5
1     A     A_2         11           58       87
2     A     A_3         14           24       54
3     B     B_1         3            6        9
4     B     B_2         1            38       77
5     B     B_3         54           13       10
```

and i also have a dataframe lis this one:

df2:

```
     col1  col2        sample1    sample2  sample3
0     A     A_0         98          57       102
2     A     A_1         6           13       5
2     A     A_2         13          52       17
3     A     A_3         8           29       50
4     B     B_0         60          75       98
5     B     B_1         3           6        9
6     B     B_2         1           8        77
7     B     B_3         2           1        10
```

So, how can I combine these dataframes, based on col1 and col2 and create a dataframe like this one:

```
     col1  col2        sample1    sample2  sample3     data1   data2   data3
0     A     A_0         98          57       102        NaN     NaN     NaN
2     A     A_1         6           13       5          2       4       5
2     A     A_2         13          52       17         11      58      87
3     A     A_3         8           29       50         14      24      54
4     B     B_0         60          75       98         NaN     NaN     NaN
5     B     B_1         3           6        9          3       6       9
6     B     B_2         1           8        77         1       38      77
7     B     B_3         2           1        10         54      13      10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pandas.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html)
The `on` argument defines what column you want to merge the dataframes on and the
`how` keyword defines what type of merge you want. Please look at the documentation to confirm what type of merge you want. But I think in this case you want the `outer` merge.

```
print(pd.merge(df1, df2, on='col2',how='outer'))
```

Comment: Hi @kinshukdua, when I try that it is removing index 0 and 4 where I have that A_0 and B_0, and I also want index 0 and 4 rows in the output dataframe.

Comment: @user14073111 I updated the answer to make it work.

Comment: Hey @kinshukdua, i just saw that when i use that line, then i have two col1_x and col1_y. How can i have only one col1 in the final dataframe?

Comment: @user14073111 I'm assuming they both have the same value, then you can delete one of the column and rename the other. I'll lyk if I find a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to base your conditions for both the values of 'col1' and 'col2', this minor adjustment would certainly help.

```
data = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['col1',col2'],how='outer')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).